# Control RaspberryPI 3 via Serial/GPIO

Tags: gpio, serial-console

So I'm working on a bit of a little project with a PI for work.

I'm making the PI into a little portable NAS where i can connect it to a network and on boot, it will email me its IP Address (if it gets one). In the case where the network is static, i want to have a way to connect to my PI's terminal and configure a static IP without the need of connecting the PI to a display and mouse and keyboard etc. I want to connect to my PI via Putty and get to the console.

I followed [this tutorial](https://spellfoundry.com/2016/05/29/configuring-gpio-serial-port-raspbian-jessie-including-pi-3/) on enabling the /dev/ttyS0 port which is the GPIO on pins 14 and 15. And from my understanding, this should allow me to do what i want but not sure what the next step is to connect the PI to my PC so i can Putty into it.

I was looking at GPIO to USB or something, but unsure what to use.

Anyone done this before or similar and knows what i should get to achieve what i want?

Many thanks!

Comment: **What is the actual problem?**  Are you simply trying to figure out the IP address of the Raspberry Pi when it connects to your network?  If you are using a DHCP server, such as a home router in standard configuration, the RPi should automatically obtain an IP address via the wired ethernet port... and also the WiFi if you've configured that interface with the network password... in the standard configuration, a RPi with be reachable via `ping raspberrypi.local` from any network host that is running an mDNS compatible service... default for GNU/Linux and MacOSx.

Comment: no im not having network issues with my PI. That was just a background detail of what im doing. I said in the event where i need to setup a static without connecting a monitor but instead use a serial cable or some sort to connect to the GPIO of the PI and access the terminal that way via putty. Once im in putty in my PI, then i can do what i want and such. I have a buddy who also does PI stuff and he told me to get a TTY to USB adapter which i found on Amazon, so im going to try that once it comes in the mail and post if it worked or not.

Comment: You should be able to connect like this: **PC -> USB to RS232 cable -> Null Modem -> RPi serial port**  ... Unfortunately, I don't believe the RPi3 has the ability to configure its built in USB port as a gadget device.

Comment: i did see that there was a shield for a serial port but im wanting to enclose the PI in a case, and thats just going to be really bulky and inconvenient for me, at least the way im trying to use it since its going to be traveling here and there. thats the reason its sending me emails with its IP that it gets from DHCP and serial for manual config.

Comment: If `/boot/cmdline.txt` includes `console=serial0,115200` (it does by default) then there will be a login console on that serial bus.  You just have to configure PuTTY, which should be reasonably simple.  **Beware** that you must make sure the adapter you have is stepped down to 3.3V or you may damage the Pi.

Comment: @goldilocks thanks. I have an adapter coming in next week so I'll keep this in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an USB to TTL cable. TTL indicates 3.3 V compatibility. "Normal" USB to RS-232 cables work with higher voltages and can damage the Pi.

Example USB to TTL cable : https://www.adafruit.com/product/954

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned in the comments, I got one from Amazon which happens to be the same one you linked. So I guess this confirms I got the right one.